# clear iframe cache issue in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am using iframe to load pdf.
`$('#iframe01').attr('src', url);`

Everytime when loading new pdf file, it shows the old one for a very short period of time.

So, I am  using `$('#iframe01').find('body').html('')` to clear the previous cached pdf when user click the different pdf file, it is working fine in Chrome.

However, when I test it in IE9, after opened the pdf and closed it, when click 2nd file, in console, it is saying: `No such interface supported` and crash.

Any reason for this happen?

Comment: Try this: `$('#iframe01').html('')`

Comment: @Tushar not working with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, `contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = ''` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add some extra data's in your URL like

```
$('#iframe01').attr('src', url + "?date="+new Date().getTime() );
```

this will be considered as every time the new url comes and erase the old data.

Hope this helps. But not tested.